# Why if statement and && don't behave similarly in this case?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a function in a script that returns an exit code of 0 if a given line number exists in a file, otherwise it returns an exit code of 1.
This is its current structure:

```
lineCont=$(sed "$1!d" "$dbFile")

if [ -z "$lineCont" ]; then
    return 1
fi
```

If I try to replace the if-statement with `[ -z "$lineCont" ] && return 1` it will return an exit code of 1 even if the line actually exists in the file. Why this happens?

Comment: This is a *guess*, but I think it's because the boolean expression is being evaluated as *false*, which would produce the same return code.

Comment: @Rfroes87 Your guess is correct, make it an answer so you can get the credit

Comment: @Rfroes87 Thanks! I forgot that using && would return 1 if the first command returned a non-zero exit code. Using "-n" to test if the variable is set to something and using || (or) instead of && solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why this happens?

Facts:

- The exit status of a function is equal to the exit status of the last command executed (or equal to what is passed to `return`).
- The exit status of a list of commands is equal to the exit status of the last command executed.
- The exit status of an if statement is the last command executed, except if no body was executed, when the exit status is 0.
- The exit status of 0 represents success, a non-zero exit status represents failure.

Consider the following function:

```
func() {
    false && return 1
}
```

First `false` returns nonzero exit status. Because it's nonzero, the `return 1` is *not* executed. Then the exit status of the whole list of commands is the exit status of last command executed. The exit status of the whole `( false && return 1 )` is equal to the exit status of `false`. Then, the exit status of the whole function is equal to the exit status of the last command executed. Ie. the exit status of `func` is equal to the exit status of `false`.

Doing `some_command && return 1` is just strange if it's the last command in a function - just do `! some_command`. Maybe you'll want to do:

```
func() {
    local linecont
    linecont=$(sed '$1!d' "$dbfile")
    [ -n "$linecont" ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your misbehaving function looks like this (x.sh):

```
set -x
function f1() {
    l=$1
    dbFile=$2
    lineCont=$(sed "$l!d" "$dbFile")
    [ -z "$lineCont" ] && return 1
}
f1   3 x.sh
echo rc=$?
f1 400 x.sh
echo rc=$?
```

Then your function is always going to return 1 because the function doesn't execute a return statement when [ -z "$lineCont" ] is false. It executes a return statement only if that expression is true and the function, by default, has a return code equal to the most recent command (which in your case is the if predicate).

Look at the execution of this for more information:

```
false # sets the return code to 1
echo rc1=$?
true # sets the return code to 0
echo rc2=$?
```

If you make the last line of your function this:

```
[ "$lineCont" ]
```

Then it should do what you want.